# Golang - Pipelines with channels and waitgroups, send on closed channel panic error

Tags: go

Folks, trying to understand, why the following code produces a `panic: send on closed channel`

The application has several stages.  The producer generates random numbers and sends them to the channel.  To simulate scenario where several workers need to be processing these messages, waiting a second, then sending them onto the final stage.

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    numOfConcurrentWorkers := 2

    sourceCH := make(chan int)
    destCH := make(chan int)

    // source stage
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, out chan int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        data := rand.Perm(10)
        for _, i := range data {
            out <- i
        }
        close(out)
    }(&wg, sourceCH)

    // mid stage
    wg.Add(numOfConcurrentWorkers)
    for c := 0; c < numOfConcurrentWorkers; c++ {
        go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, in <-chan int, out chan int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for i := range in {
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                out <- i
            }
            close(out)
        }(&wg, sourceCH, destCH)
    }

    // final stage
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, in <-chan int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := range in {
            log.Print("final ", i)
        }
    }(&wg, destCH)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mid stage every goroutine is closing the shared output channel, so when the first goroutine closes it, all the other goroutines trying to write to it will fail.

Close it when all the mid stage workers complete. Use a separate wait group for that.